# Have any Hogwarts students been killed by their house animal?

Tags: harry-potter

Have any Hogwarts students been killed by their house animal?

For example, a Hufflepuff goes walking in the forest, and gets killed by a badger.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, although probably not while they are still a student.

**Severus Snape** was killed by a snake, and he was a Slytherin student.  The murder is described in *Deathly Hallows* chapter 32.  [J. K. Rowling claims that Snape was a Slytherin in the FAQ on her old website](http://web.archive.org/web/20110721043724/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=62).

> If a teacher is head of a house, can we assume that they were sorted into those houses when they were students at Hogwarts? Is that also true for the house ghosts? So was Snape a Slytherin?
>
> Yes, if the teacher is Head of House you can indeed assume that they were pupils within that house. So Snape was very definitely a Slytherin and yes, the same is true of the house ghosts.

Comment: Snape being a Slytherin is also explicit in the books. For example in "The Prince's Tale" in *Deathly Hallows* we actually see him get sorted into Slytherin.